# Does "gradle test" run tests against the jar or raw compiled classes?

Tags: gradle

If classes, is it possible to get it to run the tests against the jar instead?

I'm using TestNG if that makes a difference.

Comment: Isn't the jar assembled from the compiled classes? What difference does it make which the test is run against?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'test' task is run agains the 'main' sourceset classpath. This means the compiled classes **and** processed resources. By convention this typically translates to *build/classes/main* and *build/resources/main*. You'll notice that running `gradle test` does not execute the 'jar' task.

If there are resources that exist only in your jar then you should probably instead configure the 'processResources' task to include those items.

```
processResources {
    from 'someStuffToGoInJar'
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The rationale of using the compiled jar is just to ensure that any resource files under `src/main/resources` can be resolved ok. Since resolving resources from a jar is fundamentally different from resolving off the filesystem, I wanted to make sure we had both paths covered.

(In the past, we've had code checked in such as `new FileInputStream(new ClassPathResource("myfile.txt").getFile())` which would work against the filesystem but not against a jar).